# How to set platform when using pip download command

Tags: python, linux, pip

I want to download some pacakges(tensorflow, keras, imbalanced, xgboost, lightgbm, catboost) for centos 7.4 and python 3.7 on mac.

How should i set platform name and ant other settings?

I used below command line

```
pip download --only-binary=:all: --python-version 3 --abi cp3m --platform manylinux1_x86_64 tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

Set version to 37:

```
pip download --only-binary=:all: --python-version 37 --abi cp37m --platform manylinux1_x86_64 tensorflow
```